# DELL Inspiron failed to load/not switching on

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron

I'm facing a problem with my Dell Inspiron 15. Am trying to switch on but unfortunately the power button is just blinked and off.

I have tried by removing battery for some time but no luck.

What would be the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried it with the battery out all together and plugged into power?

Comment: yeah, i tried but no luck

Comment: If you are lucky, it may be a loose memory stick, or even hard disk (though these are both normally locked in pretty tight).  If it doesn't compromise your warranty you could open the compartments in the base and re-seat everything

Comment: currently i tried by removing only my RAM's and re-seated as is in RAM slot. But didn't tried by removing whole compartments in the base. Really I should try this, am bit worried and I never tried opening whole base..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got solved.

**Actual detected issue: IO board got failed.**

Now it has been replaced with new IO board.

Thanks for your reply...